# Nexus Forbidden Error on download 3 rd party jar

Tags: java, maven, nexus

Since the last two days, I am unable to download any content(dependency) uploaded to the third party repository. Below is the error I get on maven build when maven tries to download from Nexus. Please help. Below is the error trace from the pom.lastupdated file.

## NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be changed without prior notice.

## Tue Dec 05 20:35:28 IST 2017

09d982e5b94dfb61c9f162ebed8644b6a8739a30@proxy.ccc.com:8080>@default-nexus-http://:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/.lastUpdated=1512486328451 
http://:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/.error=Could not transfer artifact com.rolta:etl-services:pom:1.2 from/to nexus (http://:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Access denied to: http://:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/rolta/etl-services/1.2/etl-services-1.2.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.

Comment: Your authentication does not work correctly: `Access denied to: http://:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/com/rolta/etl-services/1.2/etl-services-1.2.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden....`

Comment: Actually our proxy was restricting access to our nexus VM. I removed the proxy entries from the settings.xml and this has started working again.